# How can I make each array, within an array perform a task?

Tags: c#, arrays, udp

I am getting data with one of the following names, Adam, Bob, Cam, Dan, Earl, or Fred.

I only want certain pairs to operate on each other. Right now I have the string:

```
string list="Adam-Bob;Cam-Dan;Earl-Fred";
```

Then I split them via the semicolon

```
string[] splitList=list.Split(';');
```

Now I have an array of pairs as so

```
Adam-Bob Cam-Dan Earl-Fred
   [0]     [1]      [2]
```

Ideally, I would like to perform an operation on each of them, but instead I find that I can only do the following:
Split via ','

```
foreach (string s in splitList)
{
string firstPerson=splitList[0];
string secondPerson=splitLilst[1];

if (UDPoutputData.Contains(firstPerson)==true)
{
//record data into string for firstPerson
}

if (UDPoutputData.Contains(seoncdPerson)==true)
{
//record data into string for secondPerson
}

//if I have data for firstPerson AND secondPerson, perform operation and give me the output
}
```

Unfortunately, if I get the name Adam, followed by Cam, my operations are disorganized. Perhaps I need to automatically create a string for each name? Or is there an eloquent way of operating the data on the first array...

Comment: What does UDP mean to you? This doesn't sounds like it's "User Datagram Protocol" related?

Comment: It's a seperate UDP application that I haven't included in here. I'm mostly interested in performing functions on the array in the manner I described.

Comment: Ok, well, I would remove the `udp` tag, since the actual question isn't affected by it.

Answer (score 1):

You could get an array of arrays (of string), like this:

```
string[][] splitList = list.Split(';').Select(pair => pair.Split('-')).ToArray();
```

Then you can access `splitList[0][0]` to get `Adam`, `splitList[0][1]` would be `Bob`, `splitList[1][0]` would be `Cam`, etc.

So your loop becomes:

```
foreach (string[] pair in splitList)
{
    string firstPerson=pair[0];
    string secondPerson=pair[1];

    // ...
```